# Deploying Strapi to Production Heroku database

Tags: heroku, knex.js, strapi, heroku-postgres

I have an updated Strapi site, running V3.1.4 - we've come from a V3.0.6 site, with minimal structural changes. Strapi can connect to Postgres on my local version, and everything is fine, but when deploying to Heroku it gets more complicated.

I have a staging site using a Heroku Hobby database, with the following packages:

```
"knex": "^0.20.10",
"pg": "^8.0.3",
"pg-connection-string": "^2.3.0",
```

and my config uses:

```
options: {
        pool: {
          min: 0,
          max: 18,
          createTimeoutMillis: 30000,
          acquireTimeoutMillis: 600000,
          idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }
      }
```

and SSL is set to false.

This runs fine, but if I then deploy this to 'live' (ie using a Production database that requires SSL) I get the following error:

```
[DATABASE] [10-1] sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.249.190.208", user "XXX", database "XXX", SSL off
```

I've had this before, and as per [this post](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2009), I've taken PG down to V7.4.3, but I then get this error:

```
error KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
```

and no cannot get this to work by altering any of thee pool settings, including using:

```
ssl:true,
rejectUnauthorized: false,
```

Node and NPM are set to:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
```

I think I've read most posts around this subject but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas greatly received.

Comment: What was your solution here? Seems Heroku now requires SSL configs for the free/hobby tier for all Postgres connections?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more searching and focusing on the Self Signed issue that is a result of `no pg_hba.conf entry for host` I came across https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/6050 which helped to resolve it.